# Accessing the zip file in S3 from EC2 instance using boto3 package in Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Please find the code snippet
I need to access a zip file in S3 and access the files in the zip file for further processing

Code Snippet

1. Option 1:Live connection and reading the file content

Issue: Memory leak

```
s3_resource =  boto3.resource('s3',       
aws_access_key_id = 'XXXXXXX',       
aws_secret_access_key = 'XXXXX')

file = s3_resource.Object('xxxxxx',filePath).get()
with io.BytesIO(file['Body'].read()) as t:
t.seek(0)
with ZipFile(t, 'r') as myzip:
```

2. Option 2:Download the file to a temp file

Issue: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:(at line file=s3.download_file('bucket','filename',
                 f.name)

```
f = tempfile.TemporaryFile(delete=False)
print(f) 
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id = 'xxxxx', 
aws_secret_access_key = 'jxxx')  
file=s3.download_file('bucket','filename',
                 f.name)
with ZipFile(f.name, 'r') as myzip:
print('done')
```

Please let me know the efficient way of handling this issue